# Google map API Multiple marker click animation

Tags: google-maps-markers

Google map has multiple marker clicks. Each marker has the corresponding info-window to display the content. How do I do that, when I click a marker to display info-window, turn off the last info-window?

[Chinese — translate]
google map API中，有多个marker点击每一个marker都有对应的info-window来展示内容，请问怎么实现点击一个marker展示info-window时把上一个info-window关掉？

Answer (score 0):

The point is to new only one infowindow,

and change the content you want to show in the infowindow for each marker.

In that way,while you click the next marker,the previuos one will close automatically.

```
 infowindow.setOptions({   content: content,  });                        

 infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

Comment: You should put your code on codepan so others can help you out .